# Prove an improper double integral is convergent

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I need to prove the following integral is convergent and find an upper bound
$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{1+x^2+y^4} dx dy$$

I've tried integrating $\frac{1}{1+x^2+y^2} \lt \frac{1}{1+x^2+y^4}$ but it doesn't converge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continuing from zhw.'s answer,
$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\sqrt{r}}{2(1+r^2)}\,dr = \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{u^2\,du}{1+u^4}=\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{2}} $$
by the residue theorem, while:
$$ \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{d\theta}{\sqrt{\sin\theta}}=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{du}{\sqrt{u(1-u^2)}}=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2\pi}}\,\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^2$$
from the Euler beta function and the $\Gamma$ reflection formula. Hence we have:

> $$ \iint_{(0,+\infty)^2}\frac{dx\,dy}{1+x^2+y^4}=\color{red}{2\sqrt{\pi}\cdot\Gamma\left(\frac{5}{4}\right)^2}=2.9123736927\ldots$$

A simple upper bound may be derived from:
$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{u^2}{1+u^4}\,du \leq \int_{0}^{1}u^2\,du+\int_{1}^{+\infty}\frac{du}{u^2}=\frac{4}{3},$$
$$ \int_{0}^{1}\frac{2\,du}{\sqrt{1-u^4}}\leq\int_{0}^{1}\frac{2\,du}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}=\pi. $$

---

Another simple proof comes from:
$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{dx}{1+y^4+x^2}=\frac{\pi}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+y^4}}$$
and obviously:
$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{dy}{\sqrt{1+y^4}}\leq \int_{0}^{1}dy+\int_{1}^{+\infty}\frac{dy}{y^2}$$
giving $\color{red}{I\leq \pi}$. That can be improved through Cauchy-Schwarz inequality:
$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{du}{\sqrt{1+u^4}}\leq \sqrt{\left(\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{1+u^2}{1+u^4}\,du\right)\cdot\left(\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{du}{1+u^2}\right)}$$
leads to:

> $$ \color{red}{I} \leq \frac{\pi^2}{2\sqrt{2\sqrt{2}}}=2.93425\ldots\color{red}{< 3}.$$

Comment: Your last simple proof was exactly what I needed, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Let $y=\sqrt t$ to see the integral is

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2\sqrt t(1+x^2+t^2)} dt\  dx.$$

Go to polar coordinates $x=r\cos \theta, t = r\sin \theta$ and we have

$$\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{1}{\sqrt {\sin \theta}}\ d\theta \int_0^\infty \frac{\sqrt r}{2(1+r^2)}\ dr.$$

Both of those integrals converge.

Answer (score 0):

Finding the exact value of $\int_0^\infty\frac{dx}{a^2+x^2}$ is just a calc I exercise. Let $a=\sqrt{1+y^4}$ and see what happens...

Comment: but that implies $y$ is fixed

Comment: Huh? Yes, for each fixed $y$ you calculate $\int_0^\infty\,dx.$ Now integrate that result with respect to $y$. ???

Comment: aren't you using the fact that it is integrable to prove its integrability? can you apply Fubini without knowing if the integral converges?

Comment: I'm applying Tonelli's theorem.

Comment: we haven't seen that one in class

Comment: Fine. The context of all this is not clear. Are these Riemann integrals? What's the _definition_ of the double integral? What _do_ you know? (For example: You could take what I said and apply it to $\int_0^A\int_0^Adxdy$, then take the limit as $A\to\infty$. There's no problem with convergence for the integral over that square. But is showing that the limit of the integral over the square is finite enough? Depends on what you have or have not done in class. What method _do_ you know for showing a double integral converges?)

Comment: You might note that the same issues arise with zhu's excellent answer. In fact the same issue arises in justifying the first change of variables, then we also have to justify the switch to polar coordinates somehow. (This is definitely not meant as a criticism of his answer. Just pointing out that there are things that need to be "justified" regardless of how you do it; how you justify those things depends on what tools are legal, and there's no way _we_ can tell what's legal until  you tell us...)